# how to print list all first name

Tags: list, scala

I had a list with string first name  and last name

```
val dataList = List("Narendra MODI","Amit SHA","Donald TRUMP","Ratan TATA","Abdul KALAM")
```

I want to print all the first from the list like `Narendra,Amit,Donald,Ratan,Abdul`

could you please help me on this in scala

Comment: What did you tried? What can and can't you use? Will the names always consist pf just: `firstName lastName`?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option is to take the initial non-space characters from each string:

```
dataList.map(_.takeWhile(!_.isSpaceChar))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can map over your list and use split on space and select the 1st index.

```
scala> val dataList = List("Narendra MODI","Amit SHA","Donald TRUMP","Ratan TATA","Abdul KALAM")
dataList: List[String] = List(Narendra MODI, Amit SHA, Donald TRUMP, Ratan TATA, Abdul KALAM)

scala> dataList.map( _.split(" ").headOption.getOrElse(None))
res2: List[java.io.Serializable] = List(Narendra, Amit, Donald, Ratan, Abdul)
```

Comment: `apply` on `Array` is unsafe

Comment: didnt got you, i haven't use apply method
?

Comment: `_.split(" ")(0)` ~> `Array.apply`

Comment: Oh ok but why unsafe any reason? LIke IndexOutOfBoundsException If list is empty.

Comment: In that case one can use `headOption`

Comment: Use `flatMap()` instead of `map()`. Then you can drop the `.getOrElse()` (which, as you've written it, isn't returning the correct type).

Comment: `headOption.getOrElse(None)` makes ni sense (and lead to inconsistent return type)